# Change a page number to Hebrew

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, hebrew

I am using `Lyx`. I tried this command: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{$\aleph$}` but I got the page number `1` instead. What should I do?

Here is a minimal example, rather long mostly because of the preamble.

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-std
theorems-sec
enumitem
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "Times New Roman"
\font_sans "default" "Times New Roman"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\align center

\lang english
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
renewcommand{
\backslash
thepage}{א}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
משהו לכתוב...
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Do you want to change the appearance of a *single* page number, or would you like to paginate your *entire* document with Hebrew letters?

Comment: A single page. However if I impose \thispagestyle{empty} on each other page, that sould not be a problem. The file consists of 4 pages only.

Comment: Hi Yoav, I cant reproduce your problem, can you post a MWE? note that a LyX file is a text file, so you can open it with any text editor and post the content.

Comment: I added an example. Please pinpoint my mistake.

Comment: @YoavAvidan thanks for posting the minimal example. You might want to *additionally* (i.e., the .lyx file is useful to people like me who have LyX) export to LaTeX and post that as well. Make sure to export to the LaTeX flavor that you're using (e.g., XeTeX).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you wrote the `\renewcommand` inside a centered paragraph (that is also inside `\english` environment). Since `\renewcommand` assigns macros locally, the new format of `\thepage` has only changed inside the group of that paragraph.

To get the ERT out of this group, change the paragraph and text style settings to default. You can do that by selecting the ERT box, right click on it and select Paragraph Settings or Text Style.

This is an example that should work:

```
 #LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-std
theorems-sec
enumitem
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "Times New Roman"
\font_sans "default" "Times New Roman"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
renewcommand{
\backslash
thepage}{א}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
משהו לכתוב...
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```